# Meaning of "He drives the train on this"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [Daily Mail news website](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4091620/Spicer-says-doesn-t-Trump-s-tweets-ahead-time-hints-changes-coming-White-House-press-conferences.html),

> Incoming White House Press Secretary Sean Spicer said this week that he sees Donald Trump's tweets at the same time as everyone else – after the president-elect posts them.
>
> '**He drives the train on this**,' Spicer replied when asked by former White House Press Secretary Robert Gibbs if the GOP communications head knows what Trump plans to tweet.
>
> Spicer said 'I do not,' when Gibbs followed up and asked if he got to see the tweets ahead of time.

I do not understand clearly what is meant by "drives the train on this".

It does not seem to be about [drivetrain](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drivetrain) (of an automotive vehicle) or the phrase ["run/pull the train"](https://www.quora.com/Where-did-the-phrase-pull-a-train-originate/answer/Robert-Charles-Lee?srid=RL5x)

My guess is that it somehow connects to the fact that Trump tweets a lot. So what is it exactly?

Comment: It is the driver who is in charge of a railway locomotive.

Comment: The way I understand it is that the driver of a railway train (or even of a train of horse carriages) determines when the train stops & starts and where it goes, and all the passengers on the train have no choice but to go where the driver takes them.

Comment: Although, i’m sure not what the speaker intended to imply, but taking the train metaphor further, the train is on a predetermined path, not selected or designed by the driver. The driver has no control over where the train is going, only on when it goes and how fast.

Comment: For U.S. listeners, there is also an unmistakable (though no doubt unintended by Spicer) echo of the Grateful Dead's updapted folk lyric about the legendary trainman, Casey Jones: "Drivin' that train, high on cocaine, Casey Jones you better watch your speed!"

Comment: @SvenYargs That could well be the intended reference.

Comment: In my comment above, "updapted" should either be "updated" or "adapted"; I couldn't decide between them, and "updapted was the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"He drives the train on this"**

He is the train engineer (engine driver in BrE), and he decides when to start the engine and when to stop. He posts whatever he wants, whenever he wants to, and doesn't have to hear the GOP communications head first.

"on this" = **when it comes to tweeting**

Comment: It may be worth adding in a non-American alternative to the term _train engineer_. Perhaps it’s just me, but I’ve never heard that before (I’ve only heard _train driver_, _engine driver_, _locomotive driver_, etc.), and my immediate thought when reading this answer was that engineers don’t have a say in when the train starts and stops—they just build it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet done.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet     This is an old one from grammar school times: what kind of ears are required by a locomotive?

Answer (score 3):

To be "[in the driving seat](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-in-the-driving-seat)" means to have control over something. I think "He drives the train on this" would be an extension of this, implying that he controls this situation and that other people have to go along with it. A train passenger does not decide when the train moves.